# Referencing columns in Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a word list that I converted to Data Frame

```
  -----
| word |
  -----
| cat  |
| bird |
| dog  |
| ...  |
  -----
```

And I tried to do a letter count:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import length

letter_count_df = words_df.select(length(words_df.word))
```

I know this results to a dataframe with a single column only.

How do I refer to the only column of `letter_count_df` without using `alias`?

```
  -------------
| length(word) |
  -------------
|           3  |
|           4  |
|           3  |
|         ...  |
  -------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With name:

```
>>> letter_count_df.select(c)
DataFrame[length(word): int]
```

or col and name:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> letter_count_df.select(c))
```

with `c` being a constant:

```
>>> c = "length(word)"
```

or

```
>>> c = letter_count_df.columns[0]
```